# Trying to upgrade to PHP 7.4.9

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

PHP 7.4.9 just released and I am on ubuntu.

When I do `php -v`, I see version `7.4.8`

Tried running `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install php7.4`

But it says that I am already on the latest version:

`php7.4 is already the newest version (7.4.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3).`

My questions is how long do I have to wait? And how does this work really? Does Ubuntu add that repository or something for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP package you are using is packaged by Ondrej Sury (deb.sury. in the package name). You have to wait for this maintainer (the most famous in PHP world) to package it for Ubuntu. You can stay up to date by following [their website](https://deb.sury.org/).

Comment: Are you affiliated with deb.sury?

Comment: Absolutely not ;-) but using its packages since a few years